# Nexus oss unpack plugin privilege

Tags: maven, nexus

I have installed nexus3 oss in my linux machine. I have tried to host a html website by zipping and uploading in a raw hosted repository as mentioned in this [link](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-).

However, I couldn't set **Unpack** privilege to my deployment account. I have installed the nexus-unpack-plugin by extracting it in $NEXUS_HOME/nexus3/plugin-repository and restart the nexus, but still I can't see this privilege in my nexus settings.

Is this "Unpack" privilege need to be added manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack is currently not available in Nexus Repository Manager 3.x

Please feel free to pop over to: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS and file an issue if you are interested in this functionality in Nexus Repository Manager 3.x